# salesforce connector cannot be enabled in wso2 esb 4.8.1

Tags: wso2-esb

I have download and install connector of salesforce, but after install it by following https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Managing+Connectors+in+Your+ESB+Instance
, there is no "enable" button on the UI.

Is it because esb4.8.1 doesn't need to enable connector?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by the UI button. I have found the button which looks like "disable" button.